# C++ return value created before or after auto var destruction?

Tags: c++, locking

In C++ is a return value guaranteed to be created before automatic variables in the function are destroyed?  Notice Basket::get:

```
class Basket
{
public:
  // Gift is a struct containing safely copyable things like int or string
  Gift gift;
  // Used to protect access and changes to gift
  Mutex mutex;

  // Copy gift into present, while locked to be thread safe
  void put (const Gift & gift)
  {
    Lock lock(mutex);   // Constructor locks, destructor unlocks mutex
    this->gift = gift;  // Gift assignment operator
  }

  // Return a memberwise-copy of gift, tries to be thread safe (but is it?)
  Gift get ()
  {
    Lock lock(mutex);  // Constructor locks, destructor unlocks mutex
    return gift;       // Gift copy constructor
  }
};
```

I need Basket::get to perform its Gift copy constructor (of the temp object returned) prior to destruction of the lock object.  Otherwise the gift object being returned can be corrupted by a simultaneous call to put.

My tests show the gift copy is indeed created before lock destruction, however, is it guaranteed?  If not, I'll need to create a second temporary inside the function, such as:

```
  Gift get ()
  {
    Gift result;
    {
      Lock lock(mutex);
      result = gift;
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, the auto variable will remain in scope until after the return is finished. This is especially true if you are using a compiler that optimizes the `return`, eg:

```
Gift get() 
{ 
    Lock lock(mutex);
    return gift;
} 

Gift g = basket.get();
```

Which would be equivilent to this sequence:

```
Gift g;
Lock lock(mutex);
g = Gift(gift);
lock.~Lock();
```

May be optimized to act more like this:

```
void get(Gift &ret) 
{ 
    Lock lock(mutex);
    ret = gift;
} 

Gift g;
basket.get(g);
```

Which would be equivilent to this sequence:

```
Gift g;
Lock lock(mutex);
g = gift;
lock.~Lock();
```

In other words, a temporary can be removed during the `return`.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I needed re: a scenario of a mutex lock being destroyed after returning an rvalue.  Thanks.

Comment: So it's not guaranteed if this feature is contingent on the compiler optimising the return value. Why assume that the compiler will optimise? It's not safe to assume compiler optimisation.

Answer (score 6):

It's guaranteed. The return value is copied (if necessary) before the destruction occurs. Here's a similar question / answer that gives a good description of the sequence.

[Scope and return values in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275214/scope-and-return-values-in-c)

Comment: There is no such thing as registers in the C++ standard. (Well, there is the `register` keyword, but that lost its meaning a long time ago.) Also, most objects wouldn't fit into a single register, anyway.

Comment: If a local object was being returned, then sure, it would have to be copied before it was destroyed.  However, this is something else.  I have a data member of the class being returned, so the semantics of exactly when the copy occurs seems different.

Comment: @maxpolk You are returning the member by value. There will be a copy unless the compiler can optimize it to a reference assignment as Remy showed. If you were returning a reference or pointer the lock would still be destroyed after.

Comment: @FredOverflow - all true. I was thinking in assembly but even then my words were loose. Main point I wanted to make was that copy will occur before stack is unwound. Although has been stated, that too could be qualified by "if necessary". I'll edit the answer.