# Lifetime of local variables inside a std::async lambda function

Tags: c++, lambda, lifetime, local-variables, stdasync

In the following snippet:

```
std::future<bool> result = std::async(std::launch::async, []()
{
    std::vector<char*> someLocalVariable{GottenFromSomewhere()};
    return SomeReallyLongLastingProcessingPipeline(someLocalVariable);
});
```

I am inclined to say that `someLocalVariable` will undoubtedly outlive the `SomeReallyLongLastingProcessingPipeline()` call, even if this is all happening in a lambda passed to std::async. Is this true?

I have to mention the `std::future` is inside an object that is constructed before `SomeReallyLongLastingProcessingPipeline()` and is destructed way after that function exits.

Comment: I don't really think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437763/c-return-value-created-before-or-after-auto-var-destruction . My confusion here has to do with the `async` nature of the context.

Comment: I agree, the question would be the same if you didn't return the value and had an `std::future<void>`.

Comment: @theodor96 why you think a lambda would do something special than a regular function in this case?

Comment: @appleapple as I said from that point of view it's a no-brainer that locals don't go out of scope until function return, but my concern was that `someLocalVariable` itself depends on something that goes out of scope at the end of the method where all of this snippet is located, and that could possibly mess things up, right?

Comment: @theodor96 I don't get it, you need to explicitly capture everything you used in lambda. In your example, the lambda can not use any local variable...

Answer (score 2):

In itself the code posted by you seems ok and innocent, however a `std::vector` of `char*` made me suspicious. Your comment "...but my concern was that someLocalVariable itself depends on something that goes out of scope at the end of the method where all of this snippet is located, and that could possibly mess things up, right?" stresses my suspicion:

Yes `someLocalVariable` would outlive `SomeReallyLongLastingProcessingPipeline` but not necessarily the things you have pointed the `char*` in your `std::vector` to. Your problem is probably `GottenFromSomewhere`, which fills your `someLocalVariable` with pointers to things not alive when this whole lambda is executed. So it might live or might be already "dead" in the constructor of `someLocalVariable` and the same is true for `SomeReallyLongLastingProcessingPipeline`.

However this keeps speculation without your full code.

Use a `std::vector<std::string>` instead.

---

Update from comments:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

bool SomeReallyLongLastingProcessingPipeline(std::vector<const char*> data) {
    return data.at(0)[0] == 'L';
}

//Prefer this one
bool SomeReallyLongLastingProcessingPipeline(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const std::string>> data) {
    return data.at(0)->find('L');
}

std::future<bool> foo() {

    auto big_string_you_wont_change_until_lambda_finished = std::make_shared<std::string>("Long long text "
                                                                  "(>should be at least several dozen kB");
    //You could also use std::shared_ptr foo{new std::string("ff")}; but make_shared is safer (exception safety)

    //beware of lambda capture, DO NOT just use [&] or [&big_string_you_wont_change_until_lambda_finished]
    //use [=] or [big_string_you_wont_change_until_lambda_finished] is ok
    std::future<bool> result = std::async(std::launch::async, [big_string_you_wont_change_until_lambda_finished]()
    {
        std::vector<const char*> someLocalVariable{big_string_you_wont_change_until_lambda_finished->c_str()};
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const std::string>> someBetterLocalVariable
        {big_string_you_wont_change_until_lambda_finished};

        return SomeReallyLongLastingProcessingPipeline(someLocalVariable) || //I recommend the last one
        SomeReallyLongLastingProcessingPipeline(someBetterLocalVariable);
    });
    return result;
}

int main() {

    auto future = foo();

    std::cout << future.get() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Indeed that is exactly what is going on. I would have used a `std::vector<std::string>` but unfortunately I'm interacting with a C API taking a `char*` (not a `const char*`) and I'd rather avoid making a full copy but just trying to work around it.

Comment: Don't optimise early, it's very likely the copying of your C-strings into `std::string`s isn't even noticeable. Besides you have to if they go out of scope/aren't guaranteed to live until the lambda finishes. However, whats often used for stuff which has to be alive until  lambdas run, are `std::shared_ptr`s. So you could use `std::shared_ptr<std::string>`s. Make sure however you give your lambda a full copy of the shared ptr, they are not design to be taken by reference/pointer. Lifetime management with built-in/C-types gets really ugly and thrust me, isn't worth it. I write some example code

Comment: Does `SomeReallyLongLastingProcessingPipeline` has to write to the strings pointed to by your `char*`? Can you change  `SomeReallyLongLastingProcessingPipeline` to use a `std::string`?  Otherwise I would use `std::vector<char>`

Comment: I'm not really sure why you use `std::shared_ptr<std::string>`, but if it's for cheap copy, I would recommend move capture the string.

Comment: @appleapple There are really more important things than to `std::move`  a `std::shared_ptr`, the compiler will possibly even optimise it out.

Comment: @appleapple I just made an experiment, if notably it just causes one jump and lock instruction more, but if you look at the instructions for the future, thats not the bottleneck. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/7bFgy_

Comment: The `SomeReallyLongLastingProcessingPipeline` calls C APIs that take argc/argv-like arguments and even like to write to them, so using `std::string`s or therefore `std::shared_ptr`s to `std::string`s is not really an option. What I could have done is deep copy the `std::string::c_str()` into some `new char[]`, but as I said I was trying to avoid that

Comment: @Superlokkus well, I mean `[str = std::move(out_str)](){...}`, no `shared_ptr`

Comment: @appleapple I already recommended to the OP in the first half of my answer, to simply use a `std::string`, which of course could be moved, but in the comments, he/she said he has to use a C API with built in strings/char*. However it seems to be an AB problem and he didn't replied yet, so I just made my 2 closest guess of what he said so far.