# Return auto_ptr payload by value in C++ from function

Tags: c++, memory-management, auto-ptr

Does C++ standard guarantee that here would be no crash when returning `auto_ptr`'s payload by value from the function:

```
class Foo { ... };

std::auto_ptr<Foo> createFoo() { 
  return std::auto_ptr<Foo>(new Foo(...));
}
...
Foo getFoo() {
  std::auto_ptr<Foo> foo(createFoo());
  return *foo; /// would be here a crash?
}

/// main
const Foo& foo(getFoo());
```

What's going here accordingly to the standard: `*foo` is copied, then `foo` is destroyed and finally `return` is performed? Or there is an another order of steps?

I tested this example with GCC and there is no crash but I am not sure that it would work with another compilers.

Comment: Is there any other order that doesn't break **all** of C++?

Comment: This is fine, but auto_ptr is deprecated, so you should avoid it.

Comment: @n.m: I didn't get you, could you please expand your question more detailed?

Comment: @VaughnCato: yes, I know about its deprecated state, but I have a legacy code.

Comment: I mean that if e.g. the return statement first destroyed the result and then tried to copy it, then it would be a bit hard to write working programs, wouldn't it?

Comment: This should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275214/scope-and-return-values-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very strange code, but, yes - it is guaranteed. There is no RVO, or move semantics, so it should be ok.

Answer (score 2):

As `getFoo` returns by value, it creates (yet another) copy of the `Foo` object. After that, it doesn't matter that the original object is deleted by the `auto_ptr`.

Rather strange code though, to use an `auto_ptr` and then create a copy anyway.